# Ratio Proportion question

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> What must be subtracted from each term of the ratio $3:7$ so that the ratio becomes $2:5?$

My attempt: Let two numbers be $3x$ and $7x.$ So, $\frac{3x-y}{7x-y}=\frac25 \implies 15x-5y=14x-2y \implies y=\frac{x}3$. But the answer is given as $\frac13$ only.

I wish somebody could provide some clarifications.

Comment: Isn't it because $x=1$?  I don't think you needed to introduce $x$.

Comment: @TrevorWilson- But $x$ can be $1$ or $2$ or $3$ etc, can't it be? Say, the numbers are 6 and 14. If I subtract 1/3 from each, the ratio becomes 17:41. But If I subtract 2/3 from each, the ratio becomes 2:5 as desired. Now that I am discussing it, I am being sure that my answer is correct and the given answer is wrong. But If somebody has something to add, I'll be happy to discuss.

Comment: @Ramit, your reasoning is also correct, but it appears that when the questioner asked the question, they meant "What number must you subtract from 3, and from 7 ..."  In your example, they would have asked "What number must you subtract from 6, and from 14 ..."

Comment: That is, you should have thought "Let two numbers be $3$ and $7$" instead of "Let two numbers be $3x$ and $7x$."

Answer (score 1):

@TrevorWilson is correct.  The solution should be
$$\frac{3-y}{7-y}=\frac{2}{5}$$
then you will get $y=\frac{1}{3}$. Note that
$$\frac{3-\frac{1}{3}}{7-\frac{1}{3}}=\frac{\frac{8}{3}}{\frac{20}{3}}=\frac{2}{5}$$